# Filling in missing data using populated row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe that is missing data in a particular column. For a concrete example, take it to be df below.

```
my_list = ["A", " ",31, "A", 5,32, " " ,5, 35, "B", " " , 14, "B", 4, 23, " " , 4, 26, "B", 7, 25, " ", 7, 15]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(my_list).reshape(8,3), columns = list("xyz"))
```

which looks like

```
   x  y   z
0  A     31
1  A  5  32
2     5  35
3  B     14
4  B  4  23
5     4  26
6  B  7  25
7     7  15
```

The missing data might not necessarily be arranged as conveniently as above.

What I want to do is populate all the empty cells in column x from the case where both column x and y are populated. In the df above, for row 1, y=5 is associated with x = "A". So when I go to row 2, I will populate the x with "A". The x to y relationship should be one-to-many. So different values of y can be associated to the same valueof x. However, the y to x relationship should be unique. The desired end result is

```
   x  y   z
0  A     31
1  A  5  32
2  A  5  35
3  B     14
4  B  4  23
5  B  4  26
6  B  7  25
7  B  7  15
```

I have two questions here:

1. How do I check the relationship that x-to-y is indeed one-to-many?
2. If the relationship holds, how do I then populate the missing cells in column x with the reference row where both x and y are populated?

I tried looping over the rows and picking up the x and y column values to form a dictionary with y being the key and x the value. Then armed with the dictionary, I looped through the dataframe again to populate column x. Is there a more Pandas efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

How about, grouping on `y` and shifting `x` values, and set values of `df` where `x == ' '` ?

```
In [31]: df.loc[df.x == ' ', 'x'] = df.groupby(['y'])['x'].transform('shift')

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
   x  y   z
0  A     31
1  A  5  32
2  A  5  35
3  B     14
4  B  4  23
5  B  4  26
6  B  7  25
7  B  7  15
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quite close to the perfect solution but I also want to check that the y to x mapping is unique i.e. Question 1. So if in the original df, I add two more rows ["C", 7, 23] and [" ", 7, 42]. Using your answer, the last row gets mapped to ["C", 7, 42]. But following the rules, it could have been ["B", 7, 42]. So I want to flag these instances of non-unique mapping of y to x if they exists.